# price range filter using elastisearch-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a price range filter like the one in the image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxhAJ.png)
or something like the [spree_elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/javereec/spree_elasticsearch)

I'm new to ruby on rails can someone please help me out simple code for form view and search method

say I have the following models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  include Searchable
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

and haml views

= form_tag search_path, method: 'get', role: 'search' do
     = text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...'

I'm only interested in price range and checkboxes for filtering categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Elasticseach templates here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails)
are a good start